# C# Web Service returns objects as null from WinForms application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, asmx

I am returning a array from my web service like so:

```
   [WebMethod]
   public Test_UserData[] GetLimitUsers(int min, int max)
   {
   return UserServiceLayer.GetLimitUsers(min, max);    
   }
```

If i call this web service from my browser is shows the array and content in XML format as expected.

I then added the web reference to a winforms project. 
Bare in mine i have other web services connected in the same way between the two projects which return plain old objects and they work fine.

```
UserWS.UserWS userWebService = new UserWS.UserWS();
Test_UserData[] testUserData = userWebService.GetLimitUsers(1, 2);
```

However, when i call this web service i get the amount of objects expected but all fields are null and Boolean are false.(The same behavior with Arrays, Lists and ienumerable.)

Could someone explain why i am getting the right objects but they are all "nullified" ?

Edit:

```
<Test_UserData>
<Id_ValueIncluded>true</Id_ValueIncluded>
<Id>
<Value xmlns="http://www.blah.co.uk/JamesTest/Data/">100001</Value>
<References xmlns="http://www.blah.co.uk/JamesTest/Data/"/>
</Id>
<ExtensionData_ValueIncluded>true</ExtensionData_ValueIncluded>
<Password_ValueIncluded>true</Password_ValueIncluded>
<Password>h</Password>
<UserName_ValueIncluded>true</UserName_ValueIncluded>
<UserName>h</UserName>
<OutputData>
<Type_ValueIncluded>true</Type_ValueIncluded>
<Type>Test_User</Type>
</OutputData>
</Test_UserData>
```

Comment: How does the Test_UserData class look like ?

Comment: Did you tried in poster ... ???

Comment: How accessible are the Test_UserData properties?

Comment: They are public, with get/set

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: Sadly, I have no choice in what technology to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end it was a namespace problem when using the asmx file with winforms.